# Which brokerage lets you buy Bitcoin or Bitcoin related stocks for your IRA account?

Tags: investing

I am looking to setup a IRA, but unsure which brokerage lets you trade or just hodl bitcoin or bitcoin related assets in your IRA. Which brokerage is crypto friendly?